# ruby 1.8.7 RUBYOPT (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, fedena

Just installed ruby 1.8.7 in my win10 pc 64bit. When I open the cmd with ruby appear this error:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i386-mingw32]
ruby.exe: illegal switch in RUBYOPT: -E (RuntimeError)
```

Installed in C:\Ruby187

How can I solve it? I need this version of ruby to install Fedena.

Thank you!

Comment: You've installed a 32-bit ruby on a 64-bit machine. That's probably the first problem. Beyond that, ruby 1.8.7 is **OLD** and hasn't been supported in years ... I'd wager  you may encounter a bunch more errors trying to run this on a modern Windows 10 operating system. If you really want to run this old project, you might be better off using a VM/container with a compatible old operating system.

Comment: I wonder why did you choose a version of Ruby that was retired almost [six years ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/)? Why not a version that is up-to-date and maintained?

Comment: @spickermann Because they are trying to run an old project called [`fedena`](https://projectfedena.org/install)

Comment: Someone needs to update Fedena. That's getting dangerously out of date.

Comment: Better to find another program to install. I give up. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My ancient manuals indicate that `-E` wasn't added until Ruby 1.9, hence the error message.  Source: page 38 of "The Ruby Programming Language (Covers Ruby 1.8 and 1.9)" (2008) by Flanagan & Matsumoto.